# Jquery ONE function PURE js

Tags: javascript, jquery

there! i have a problem when creating `one` function just like `JQUERY` does.

here is the action : https://jsfiddle.net/77yzLt6v/

**one time execution event**

HTML :

```
<div id="justOnce">click me!</div>

function one(dom, event, callback) {
    dom.addEventListener(event, function(e) { // add event
        this.removeEventListener(event, callback); // remove it
    }); 

}    
one(document.getElementById("justOnce"), "click", function() {

    alert("this alert only show once time");

});
```

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Comment: you dont want to use pure jquery code?

Comment: you never call `callback` in the listener callback, removeListener does not remove the right function as you added an anonymous function as listener

Comment: @mmativ, yeah, i want to learn how jquery does it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code binds an event handler that removes `callback` as an event handler.

The only problem is … you never bound `callback` as an event handler in the first place.

You want something more like this:

```
function one(dom, event, callback) {
    function handler(e) {
        callback.call(this, e);
        this.removeEventListener(event, handler);
    }
    dom.addEventListener(event, handler); 
}
```

i.e.

- You need to call the `callback`
- You need to remove the event handler you actually bound

Comment: `callback.call(this, e);` ... +1

Answer (score 5):

New standard supports this, but don't work in any browser yet ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=once))

```
window.addEventListener('resize', console.log, {once: true})
```

polyfill:

```
;(function(){
    let p = document.createElement('p')
    let count = 0
    let event = new CustomEvent('x')

    p.addEventListener('x', () => {i++})
    p.dispatchEvent(event)
    p.dispatchEvent(event)

    if (i != 2) return

    for (let obj of [Window, Element]) {
        let orig = obj.prototype.addEventListener
        function addEventListener(type, callback, opts) {
            let args = Array.from(arguments)
            if(opts && opts.once) {
                function handler(e) {
                    callback.call(this, e)
                    this.removeEventListener(type, handler)
                }
                args[1] = handler
            }
            orig.apply(this, args)
        }

        obj.prototype.addEventListener = addEventListener
    }
}())
```